# How can I output the CDF version inside a C# Razor template in 2sxc?

Tags: razor, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a template that has an image tag inside of it. I want to append the DNN CDF version to the image. So for example, when I increment the CDF version and skin.css?cdv=74, then the image tag inside of my 2sxc razor templates will also get pushed to src="@Content.Image?cdv=74" so any updates to the image don't get stuck with browser caching. Is this possible and how would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want it on the server, I believe the PortalSettings in newer Dnns (not in v7) has it https://dnndocs.com/api/DotNetNuke.Abstractions.Portals.IPortalSettings.html#DotNetNuke_Abstractions_Portals_IPortalSettings_CdfVersion

So probably `@Dnn.Portal.CdfVersion`

Comment: Ahh, amazing. This is it and it ouputs the portal version as expected. Is there a way to get the instance CDF version?

Comment: I think the portal is the site - so that should be the instance CDF -or do you mean something else by instance-cdf?

Comment: CDF can be global, or portal. Most of my sites use the global CDF setting (instance wide for all portals).

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can get it using the servicesFramework via the following:

```
serviceFramework.get("ServerSettingsPerformance", "GetPerformanceSettings")
```

[Here is an example](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/develop/Dnn.AdminExperience/ClientSide/Servers.Web/src/services/performanceTabService.js#L12-L46) of how it is done within DNN.

Comment: Thanks. How would I write this in C# Razor template in a 2sxc app?

Comment: This client-side code (JavaScript), which you can use within the 2sxc Razor template.